# How to prove this problem about Galois group of a polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> problem:Let $F$ be the field of rational function in $n$ variable $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ over
> a field $K$ with characteristic $0$,let $f(X)=X^n-e_1X^{n-1}+e_2X^{n-2}-\cdots+(-1)^ne_0$.If $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are the root of $f$ in a splitting field $E$ over $F$,    let $G=Gal(E/F)$, then $G\cong S_n$.

> confuse: i think we need addition a condition:$\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are distinct,because  if we assume $f$ has $m$ distinct root,then we can see $G≤S_m$,but from the result,$G\cong S_n$,then $m=n$?

*My attempt*: we can see each $e_i$ is elementary symmetric function of the $\alpha_i$,and note $F=K(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$,then i want to prove any element of $S_n$ can extend a autmophism of $E$, then it fixes each $e_i$,so fixes $F$.we know $E=F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$,we know $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ are algebra over $F$,then $E=F(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ is a collection of some polynomial in n variable $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$.let $σ∈S_n$ def φ
φ:   $E \to E$
$g(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n) \mapsto g(σ(\alpha_1),\cdots,σ(\alpha_n))$ i want to prove φ is automorphis of $E$, but we must to check it is well defind,i don't know how to do?

Comment: The $e_i$ are the variables which generate the field of rational functions, which I take to imply that they are algebraically independent. Hence the roots $\alpha_i$ are distinct; equal roots gives an algebraic relation between the $e_i$.

Comment: What ancientmathematician said. If there were a repeated root, the discriminant of $f$ would have to vanish. But the discriminant is a non-zero polynomial of the coefficients $e_i$. Because those variables are independent, no such polynomial can exist. You seem to cling to the thinking that the $e_i$s are elements of $K$ when, in fact, they are independent variables. For a simple to follow example let $n=2$, $e_1=Y$, $e_2=Z$, when $$f(X)=X^2-YX+Z$$ and
$$d(f)=d(Y,Z)=Y^2-4Z.$$ The polynomial $d(Y,Z)$ is not the constant polynomial zero. Hence it is not the zero element of $F=K(Y,Z)$.